# Checking if all inserts are successful on foreign keys

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a master devices table that is linked to other tables (specific device info tables) via their ID (FK).

So what my create form does is inserting the specific device type info (for example PC HDD size, OS...) into the apropriate device type table (i have one for each device type), and then I take the $this->db->insert_id() and insert it into the master device table together with the general device info (like date bought, warrant expiration date and so on).

This works perfectly. However - if for any reason the data for the master table is not valid - the second query will fail, and leave me with the inserted row in the appropriate device type table.

Is there a way of checking if the query will be successful BEFORE actually executing the full function inside my model? Or - is it possible to roll-back the changes if the 2nd query (or 3rd,4th... if I have multiple inserts) fails?

Comment: I think you better examine the reason for why the second insert query fails, why and how do the invalid data get into your program? Are you forgetting to escape some string? Something else?

Comment: Ah, it's not that the query fails - I'm just wondering in general - is there a way to make sure of the inserts in the code itself. My inserts work because I set the front validation with jQuery plus the CI validation on the backend so that's pretty much secure when it comes to inserting and processing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it all in a single transaction. Either it all succeeds or none of it does.

Comment: From the CI documentation:

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
    $this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
    $this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
    $this->db->trans_complete(); 

does this work with regular active record CI methods? I don't want to have pure SQL queries in my code

Comment: These are updates, not queries. The ACID properties of transactions guarantee the behaviour I described. It is a property of the database: it has nothing to do with CI, or PHP either. I don't know what your last sentence means, but you have to use whatever technique meets your requirement.

Comment: OK, usually I just use CI active record to write the queries - I don't write SQL in my code. From the CI documentation, it looks like you need to pass a MYSLQ query string into $this->db->query() which I would not like. 

So I was wondering if I could just wrap my current CI active record code in $this->db->trans_start() and $this->db->trans_complete() instead?

Comment: Just checked it out myself and it works. I made 1 query out of 3 fail on purpose just to see and none of the first 3 got inserted while the CI active record was inside $this->db->trans_begin(); Thank you :)